# Dotnet updating the database in a certain time interval

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have an api made with dotnet. I want to make a transaction every 24 hours and update the database. For this, I created a service derived from the IHostedService class, but I could not take action because the data I wanted to update was tracked by the other local API services. Is it wrong to use IHostedService for this process?

```
public class DailyNotificationRightRegenerative : IHostedService
{
    private Timer timer;
    private MainDbContext _dbContext;
    public DailyNotificationRightRegenerative(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _dbContext = serviceProvider.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MainDbContext>();
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        timer = new Timer(checkAndRegenerateRights, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) => throw new NotImplementedException();

    private void checkAndRegenerateRights(object state)
    {
        var allRestaurants = _dbContext.Restaurants;

        foreach (var restaurant in allRestaurants)
        {
            if (restaurant.DailyNotificationRight != 3)
            {
                restaurant.DailyNotificationRight = 3;
                _dbContext.Set<Restaurant>().Update(restaurant); //error here: "The instance of entity type 'Restaurant' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked.
                _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem because I used the using and SaveChanges statements in the wrong place.

[image]

Comment: If you only want to update a single field in all rows, don't use EF. There's no reason to load the  entire table in memory. A *single* `UPDATE Restaurants SET DailyNotificationRight=3 WHERE DailyNotificationRight!=3` is enough and will finish a lot faster than the Load, Modify,Update you perform now

Comment: If you use SQL Server or another database with scheduled jobs, you can schedule that SQL statement on the database itself